# for loop with two variables Shell

Tags: shell, unix, for-loop

I want to compare two variables rkps and rrtt against fixed values and if both conditions satisfied increase counter by 1 . I have written shell for loop like below , Is this is correct way?

Also anyway to initialize both variables in one for loop stead off

```
count=0
for rkps in 1 2 3 4
do
for rrtt in 2 3 4 1

do
    echo "rkps = $rkps"
    echo "rrtt =$rrtt"
        if [[ "$rkps" -ge 1 && "$rrtt" -ge 2 ]]; then
        echo "Read Kb/s value greater than 1Mbps and RRTT greater than 2 msec"
        count=$(($count +1))
        fi
done
done

 if [ $count -gt 1 ]; then
 echo " issue exists"
 fi
```

Note : I want to compare if 1st value in rkps > 1 && first value in rrtt -ge 2 and then second, third values etc .
-Thanks

Comment: Well, If you want to run your check for every value in rkps E.g: 1 for all values in rrtt i.e. 2, 3, 4, 1. Then your two for loop solution is appears ok. I am not sure you do this aforementioned behavior in single for loop.

Comment: @Msameer  Actually I want to compare if rkps values (one after another ) > 1 and values in rrtt (one after another ) > 2. if both conditions are true then increase count by 1.

Comment: Off-topic: Replace `count=$(($count +1))` with `((count++))`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays):

```
arr_rkps=(1 2 3 4)
arr_rrtt=(2 3 4 1)

for i in 0 1 2 3
do
   echo "rkps=${arr_rkps[i]}, rrtt=${arr_rrtt[i]}"
done
```

When you want to iterate through the complete array, you can use

```
arr_rkps=(1 2 3 4)
arr_rrtt=(2 3 4 1)

for i in ${!arr_rkps[@]}
do
   echo "rkps=${arr_rkps[i]}, rrtt=${arr_rrtt[i]}"
done
```

Comment: `${!arr_rkps[@]}` , how this  list index values in  arr_rrtt  array as you mentioned only arr_rkps array name?

Comment: `echo ${!arr_rkps[@]}` will give `0 1 2 3`, the same as the hardcoded solution. When both arrays have the same size, adding items to both arrays will keep the code working.

Comment: Or make it more secure, and first determine the minimum value of `${!arr_rkps[@]}` and `${!arr_rrtt[@]}`.

Answer (score 1):

This below script is an extension of @walter-a's solution & he deserves all the credit. We have initialized two arrays & are computing min length. 
Finally, looping for every value in array(0 to minLen) and performing a check & incrementing counter.

```
count=0
rkps_arr=(1 2 3 4)
rrtt_arr=(2 3 4 1)
minLen=$(( (${#rkps_arr[@]} < ${#rrtt_arr[@]}) ? ${#rkps_arr[@]} : ${#rrtt_arr[@]} ))

echo "MinLen:${minLen}"
for((i=0; i< minLen; i++))
do
    rkps=${rkps_arr[i]}
    rrtt=${rrtt_arr[i]}
    echo "rkps=${rkps}"
    echo "rrtt=${rrtt}"
    if [[ "$rkps" -ge 1 && "$rrtt" -ge 2 ]]; then
     echo "Read Kb/s value greater than 1Mbps and RRTT greater than 2 msec"
     ((count++))
    fi
done

echo "Overall status"
if [ $count -gt 1 ]; then
 echo " issue exists"
fi
```

Comment: More succinctly: `minLen=$(( (${#rkps_arr[@]} < ${#rrtt_arr[@]}) ? ${#rkps_arr[@]} : ${#rrtt_arr[@]} ))` — 1 line replacing 8.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Thank you, It was too verbose and unnecessary. I have tweaked per your suggestion.

Comment: Replace `count=$(($count +1))` with `((count++))`

Comment: @WalterA, Thank you for you suggestion to use more concise increment operator. I have edited the post per your input.